# change rails environment in the mid of testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to change the environment variable of rails in testing

Comment: This is probably a really bad idea.

Answer (score 81):

You could do

```
Rails.stub(env: ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
```

Then `Rails.env`, `Rails.development?` etc will work as expected.

With RSpec 3 or later you may want to use the new "zero monkeypatching" syntax (as mentioned by @AnkitG in another answer) to avoid deprecation warnings:

```
allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
```

I usually define a `stub_env` method in a spec helper so I don't have to put all that stuff inline in my tests.

An option to consider (as suggested in [a comment here](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2011/06/stubbing-out-rails-env/)) is to instead rely on some more targeted configuration that you can set in your environment files and change in tests.

Comment: Thanks self! Found this and was about to upvote, then noticed I wrote it myself 6 months ago…

Comment: Good answer here.  I too think its generally bad to have places in your code littered with Rails.env or Rails.development?, but this helped me add test coverage to some legacy code.

Comment: You can use `'production'.inquiry` instead of `ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new('production')` (see [`String#inquiry`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/inquiry))

Comment: after putting in a debugger, and running `Rails.env`, I am getting the correct environment specified, but my application is still behaving in the wrong environment (I can tell by testing my env variables). any idea why?

Comment: @NoamHacker Changing the env like in this answer will only change it for code that checks the env at a later point in time. In your case, maybe stuff happens on app boot or similar, and uses whatever env is configured at that time?

Comment: Yes you're correct, that's why it was behaving that way., so I'll have to try another solution. Thanks!

Comment: @NoamHacker, this sounds like a well dangerous idea!?

Comment: What's the difference between stubbing it, and actually changing it? I realize changing it could be bad, because of the global effect that would have, but stubbing it on `Rails` would have the same down side, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Stubbing it will automatically restore it after, so it doesn't leak between tests. I'm not sure off the top of my head if there's a practical difference between stubbing or setting-for-real-and-making-sure-to-reset-it – if you or anyone else digs into that, please share!

Comment: `stubs` with `s` in the end otherwise you'll get a no method error, so for a final `Rails.stubs(env: "production".inquiry)`

Comment: @RichSteinmetz Using what library? Older RSpec used `stub`.

Comment: @HenrikN sorry, missed to clarify, I was on minitest Mocha there.

Answer (score 19):

Rspec 3 onwards you can do

```
it "should do something specific for production" do 
  allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("production"))
  #other assertions
end
```

Comment: thank you for posting this, this is a better syntax for rspec >= 3

Comment: I added a debugger right after this statement, but when testing my environment variables, I was still getting them from the wrong environment - not the one specified in the statement. any suggestions?

Comment: @NoamHacker What kind of debugger ? what is `puts Rails.env` giving you?

Comment: @AnkitG, thanks for the reply. I am using byebug, and `Rails.env` is giving me "production". But, if I try `ENV['MY_VARIABLE']`, it will give me a test version rather than a production version

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes returning a different environment variable can be a headache (required production environment variables, warning messages, etc).

Depending on your case, as an alternate you may be able to simply return the value you need for your test to think it's in another environment. Such as if you wanted Rails to believe it is in production for code that checks `Rails.env.production?` you could do something like this:

```
it "does something specific when in production" do 
  allow(Rails.env).to receive(:production?).and_return(true)
  ##other assertions
end
```

You could do the same for other environments, such as `:development?`, `:staging?`, etc. If you don't need the full capacity of returning a full environment, this could be another option.

Comment: Nice and simple - Thank you!

Comment: For my use case, I only wanted the second call to `Rails.env.production?` to be true since the first call needed to be false for WebMock so I opted for `allow(Rails.env).to receive(:production?).and_return(false, true).twice`

Answer (score 0):

As a simpler variation on several answers above, this is working for me:

```
allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return('production')
```

Or, for as I'm doing in shared_examples, pass that in a variable:

```
allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(target_env)
```

I suspect this falls short of the `...StringInquirer...` solution as your app uses additional methods to inspect the environment (e.g. `env.production?`, but if you code just asks for `Rails.env`, this is a lot more readable. YMMV.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using something like rspec, you can stub Rails.env to return a different value for the specific test example you're running:

```
it "should log something in production" do
  Rails.stub(:env).and_return('production')
  Rails.logger.should_receive(:warning).with("message")
  run_your_code
end
```

Comment: Because it only works if you do string comparisons. Can't use it "natively" e.g. the following does not work `Rails.env.production?`

Comment: I had a hard time getting Rails.stub(:env) to work in rails 3.2.  Not sure why.