# restrict rspec test case to development environment/database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sqlite

I am having issues writing a test case for one of my controller actions which uses MySQL syntax. This is because my test environment database is sqlite3, so the syntax is not recognized.

I was looking for a way to customize which environment my test case runs in, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9119087/4926817), which I tried here:

```
Rspec.describe MyController, type :controller do

    before do
        allow(Rails).to receive(:env).and_return(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new("development"))
    end

    ... my actual tests ...
```

but, it didn't work; I am still getting a

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such function

Any suggestions?

Comment: I realize it's not what you're asking for input on, but why are you trying to run a spec in the development environment and not test?

Comment: @tvon I want the test to use the mysql database in this case rather than sqlite

Comment: Further off topic, but if you run MySQL in production then it is best to use MySQL in testing as well (and to drop sqlite entirely).  That aside, can you give more information about the error you are receiving?  It is not obviously related to your code sample.  Also, what does your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: @tvon thank you for your help. I found an alternate solution outside of my rspec test cases so I should be fine